Unable to start thrift-server due to class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter
On starting spark-thrift-server using

java 1.8,
spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3 and
hadoop-3.3.6...

spark-submit showing the job is submitted, running and completed within few seconds successfully however getting error as below -
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
MultiException[java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter, java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter]

Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter

[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter]

On checking, hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy jar, found hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.3.6.jar is there in hadoop as well as in spark both ->
$  jar -tf $SPARK_HOME/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.3.6.jar | grep AmIpFilter
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/disk1/tmp
org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/webproxy/amfilter/AmIpFilter.class

$  jar -tf $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.3.6.jar | grep AmIpFilter
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/disk1/tmp
org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/webproxy/amfilter/AmIpFilter.class

$ echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR && echo $SPARK_HOME && echo $HADOOP_HOME
.../hadoop-3.3.6/etc/hadoop
.../spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3
.../hadoop-3.3.6


Try using Java 11... 8 is end of life
